# React, pass component as a child and then render it with new prop

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a modal wrapper. where I reuse the bootstrap modal and make it a component that receives a component "x" as a child and when I render component "x" I can send a prop like handleclosemodal() to the component "x".

Im doing something like this, sending the component as a prop:

```
<Modal component={<ComponentForm onSubmit={addComment} />}/>
```

Which works fine, when I render it in the Modal like this:

```
const Modal = (props) => {
const handleclosemodal = () => {
   codeToCloseModalHere...
}
return (
    <div> 
    {props.component}
    </div>
)
}
```

But I need I need to send **handleclosemodal** in **props.component** in the Modal and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do it. Using cloneElement in the Wrapper

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.component,
       {propFromWrapper:Variable/function})}
```